# Group collection by created_at and file relation

Tags: laravel, thephpleague-fractal

I have this relation:

Each user has gallery and gallery hasMany files.

Two users can have a gallery of the same date.

This is the output JSON response:

```
User1 {
 galleries: {
  created_at: 23.04.2019.
  files: [
    {
     path: "path/to/file.jpg"
    },
    {
     path: "path/to/file2.jpg"
    },
  ]
 }
},
User2 {
 galleries: {
  created_at: 23.04.2019.
  files: [
    {
     path: "path/to/file3.jpg"
    },
    {
     path: "path/to/file4.jpg"
    },
  ]
 }
}
```

I need somehow to group galleries by created_at value, but to keep all files in same JSON response, for the groupped galleries object. Like this:

```
Users {
 galleries: {
  created_at: 23.04.2019.
  files: [
    {
     path: "path/to/file.jpg"
    },
    {
     path: "path/to/file2.jpg"
    },
    {
     path: "path/to/file3.jpg"
    },
    {
     path: "path/to/file4.jpg"
    },
  ]
 }
},
```

I tried to use `->groupBy('galleries.created_at')`, but that I get this - first file from the first gallery, first file from the second gallery

```
Users {
 galleries: {
  created_at: 23.04.2019.
  files: [
    {
     path: "path/to/file.jpg"
    },
    {
     path: "path/to/file3.jpg"
    },
  ]
 }
},
```

Comment: Can you show, how do you build your Collection?

Comment: I use fractal transformers with

`return $this->collection($user->galleries, new GalleryTransformer());` if you mean that

Comment: Probably better to look at the package documentation. Might be not pure Laravel question. I can't guess what's inside `GalleryTransformer` :)

Answer (score 0):

Before passing data into a Fractal Transformer, it's a matter of getting the right data. 
 Your desired output looks to be a listing of `File`s organized by the `Gallery` date.  It doesn't really have anything to do with `Users` (unless you plan to later scope the returned data).  That being said, Eloquent relationships won't really help here since we're not dealing with a single model's relationships, and we can just use the Laravel query builder and use the `groupBy` Collection helper function to organize the results.

It's up to you where to put this method; it could easily go into a controller method, but if you are planning on scoping the results (e.g. to certain `User`s, or for certain dates as below), you might have it live in the model.

```php
// Gallery.php

public static function filesByGalleryDate($date = null) {
    $query = DB::table('gallery')
        ->leftJoin('files', 'galleries.id', '=', 'files.gallery_id')
        ->select('galleries.created_at', 'files.*')
        ->orderBy('galleries.created_at');

    $result = $date == null 
        ? $query->get()
        : $query->where('galleries.created_at', $date)->get();

    return $result->groupBy('created_at')

        // for each date, convert inner stdClasses to arrays
        ->map(function($date) { 
            return $date->map(function($file) { 
                return (array) $file; 
            }); 
        });
}
```